# what is slow parameter in mocha?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, protractor, mocha.js

When we define `mochaOpts` in Protractor, we define one parameter as slow. I do not understand what is the use of that parameter. I tried changing it's value but I can't see any change in test execution time.

```
mochaOpts: {
   reporter: 'spec',
   slow: 1000,
}
```

Answer (score 20):

According to [the documentation](https://mochajs.org/#test-duration) its used for testing

> -s, --slow
>
> Specify the "slow" test threshold, defaulting to 75ms. Mocha uses this
> to highlight test-cases that are taking too long.
>
> To tweak what's considered "slow", you can use the slow() method:
>
> ```
> describe('something slow', function() {
>   this.slow(10000);
>
>   it('should take long enough for me to go make a sandwich', function() {
>     // ...
>   });
> });
> ```

Comment: It's a real shame their api docs are not as verbose as their front page.