# How to put a "slow" label in Jest

Tags: jestjs

With Mocha there exists a function `slow(time)` that says after which running time threshold a test is "slow" and labelled as such ([docs](https://mochajs.org/api/mocha#slow)).

Is there an alternative in Jest? I have not found any.

Comment: _Where_ did you not find any? Did you read the docs? https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#slowtestthreshold-number

Comment: It seems to be for the global config, not for a single describe as in mocha...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33121196/10140665